# Flutter webview intercept and add headers to all requests

Tags: android, flutter, webview, interceptor

Using the webview_flutter package i could load my website and add session cookies to the initial URL.

```
_controller.future.then((controller) {
  _webViewController = controller;
  Map<String, String> header = {'Cookie': 'ci_session=${widget.sessionId}'};
  _webViewController.loadUrl('https://xxxx.com', headers: header);
});
```

In order to keep the session going i need to add the same header for all requests not just for the initial one.
Is there any way to intercept all requests and modify them by adding headers to them?

the closest thing i found was `navigationDelegate`  but it only returns a `NavigationDecision` which isn't useful in my case.

Comment: Have u found a solution for webview_flutter package

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use my plugin [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview), which is a Flutter plugin that allows you to add inline WebViews or open an in-app browser window and has a lot of events, methods, and options to control WebViews.

If you need to add custom headers for each request, you can use the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` event (you need to enable it using `useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true` option).

Instead, if you need to add cookies to your WebView, you can just use the `CookieManager` class (`CookieManager.setCookie` method to set a cookie).

Here is an example that set a cookie (named `ci_session`) in your WebView and also set a custom header (named `My-Custom-Header`) for each request:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  InAppWebViewController webView;
  CookieManager _cookieManager = CookieManager.instance();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _cookieManager.setCookie(
      url: "https://github.com/",
      name: "ci_session",
      value: "54th5hfdcfg34",
      domain: ".github.com",
      isSecure: true,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('InAppWebView Example'),
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              child: InAppWebView(
            initialUrl: "https://github.com/",
            initialHeaders: {'My-Custom-Header': 'custom_value=564hgf34'},
            initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
              crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                debuggingEnabled: true,
                useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true
              ),
            ),
            onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
              webView = controller;
            },
            onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {},
            onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) async {
              List<Cookie> cookies = await _cookieManager.getCookies(url: url);
              cookies.forEach((cookie) {
                print(cookie.name + " " + cookie.value);
              });
            },
            shouldOverrideUrlLoading: (controller, shouldOverrideUrlLoadingRequest) async {
              print("URL: ${shouldOverrideUrlLoadingRequest.url}");

              if (Platform.isAndroid || shouldOverrideUrlLoadingRequest.iosWKNavigationType == IOSWKNavigationType.LINK_ACTIVATED) {
                controller.loadUrl(url: shouldOverrideUrlLoadingRequest.url, headers: {
                  'My-Custom-Header': 'custom_value=564hgf34'
                });
                return ShouldOverrideUrlLoadingAction.CANCEL;
              }
              return ShouldOverrideUrlLoadingAction.ALLOW;
            },
          ))
        ])),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I ended up using it despite having some other problems. Gonna mark it as right answer anyway.

Comment: For any other errors/problems related to the plugin, you can post them in the issue section

Comment: does this work on iOS?

Answer (score 2):

in flutter_webview case

```
onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
            this.webViewController = webViewController;
          },
onPageStarted: (url) {
            webViewController.loadUrl(url, headers: headers);
          },
```

use this

Comment: If a user clicks a button to load a new page i.e /login.html, could you add the header as well?