# Intercept Requests in Network - Flutter in app WebView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-inappwebview

I am building a simple application using Flutter. (dart)

I created a webView using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview and opened a random YouTube video in it. The thing is I want to read all the requests/calls that are called by YouTube's link.
[Network logs image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xr99.png)

I want to intercept these requests/calls and do something with them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62151219/6543507

Comment: https://inappwebview.dev/docs/in-app-webview/webview-options/

Comment: https://inappwebview.dev/docs/in-app-webview/webview-events/