# Get post request body on webview - Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, webview

I'm trying to intercept a specefic post request and get it's body when I load a page using flutter's [InAppWebView](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) package.

On iOS [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61482001/flutter-webview-intercept-and-add-headers-to-all-requests), which uses "shouldOverrideUrlLoading" to check on all the requests, works perfectly. But on Android seems like the navite Chrome browser of the Android OS doesn't allow the inAppWebView package to catch post requests.

Also, i'm able to get the all the requests URL's by using "shouldInterceptFetchRequest" from the InAppWebView package but not their bodies, which is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, however by adding this header to the URLRequest my issue is fixed.

```
 headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
```